# Bot Framework Composer Error: Unable to get a value for KnowledgeBaseId from state

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, bot-framework-composer

I'm learning how to use the Bot Framework Composer v2.0.0.

I have created a bot using the Core Bot with QnA Maker Template:

[image]

I have added the appropriate QnA Maker and Luis keys to the configuration.

When I run the bot and ask it a question I get the following error:

[image]

I am not able to find anything regarding this error, I have verified the existence of the resources and the keys and have added the knowledge base information to the settings so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

[image]

Appreciate any help.

Comment: We had a similar [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/6358) reported a few months back, which got resolved after clearing the browser cache. Can you give it a try and see if it helps resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your Language Understanding authoring key, QnA Maker subscription key and add them again manually. Restart your Bot.